# AngualrJS routeProvider routing to the wrong template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've the following 2 routes in my `app.js` file, for some reason I don't know when I try to navigate to `/clients/new-invoice` I see the `/clients/:clientID` route and template. The only way I can go to the correct page is to remove the `/clients/:clientID` route.

Also I have noticed that this started to happen only after I added the `:clientID` to the route below.

Can someone please help me by telling me what exactly I am doing wrong here?

```
    $routeProvider.when('/clients/:clientID', 
            {     templateUrl: 'templates/client-profile-view.html', 
                  controller: 'ClientsController',
                  title: 'Client Profile',
                  data: {
                     auth: true,
                     plevel: [5] 
                  }                
            });    


    $routeProvider.when('/clients/new-invoice', 
            {     templateUrl: 'templates/new-invoice.html', 
                  controller: 'InvoicesController',
                  title: 'New Invoice',
                  data: {
                     auth: true,
                     plevel: [5] 
                  }                
            });
```

Comment: my guess here is, that /clients/new-voice is interpreted by $routeProvider as /clients/:new-voice and searches for a client with the id 'new-voice'.
you can add a new route for your detail views e.g.: /clients/details/:clientID

Comment: @nilsK Well I thought of this solution, but I can't believe that this is the only way to overcome this problem in AngularJS, I mean what if your client insisted on having /clients/:clientID for viewing client profile and /clients/new-invoice for new invoice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to change the order, place `/clients/:clientID` after `/clients/new-invoice`. Order matters. All regex paths should be defined after static paths.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use first the more specific matches, and last, the generic matches:

```
$routeProvider.when('/clients/new-invoice', 
        {     templateUrl: 'templates/new-invoice.html', 
              controller: 'InvoicesController',
              title: 'New Invoice',
              data: {
                 auth: true,
                 plevel: [5] 
              }                
        })

.when('/clients/:clientID', 
        {     templateUrl: 'templates/client-profile-view.html', 
              controller: 'ClientsController',
              title: 'Client Profile',
              data: {
                 auth: true,
                 plevel: [5] 
              }                
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try propertie `caseInsensitiveMatch`

```
$routeProvider.when('/clients/new-invoice', 
{     templateUrl: 'templates/new-invoice.html', 
      controller: 'InvoicesController',
      caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
      title: 'New Invoice',
      data: {
      auth: true,
      plevel: [5] 
      }                
});
```

I'm not sure that it works

or just add this route in first position

Answer (score 0):

i discussed this with a colleague, who implemented our routeProvider. as i thought: without some kind of preg matching mechanic (is my parameter an integer/uuid or a string like 'new-voice'?), this wont work. think about this example:

/clients/:clientID => get your clients details

/client/:clientID/new-invoice => get a specific clients new-invoice

/clients/new-invoice => get all clients new-invoice

but well, if you are forced to a routing as described in your example, you have to find another solution, like preg matching parameters.

hope i could help a bit,
greetings